# Como remover parênteses de valores num array?

Tags: php

Tenho um array e preciso remover todos os parênteses de todos os **valores** desse array. Segue o array:

```
$array = array(
    "chave1" => "(valor1)",
    "chave2" => "(valor2)",
    "chave3" => "(valor3)"
);
```

Preciso que fique assim:

```
$array = array(
    "chave1" => "valor1",
    "chave2" => "valor2",
    "chave3" => "valor3"
);
```

Como posso fazer isso usando o php?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Pode usar `array_map()`, para aplicar uma função anônima em cada item do array. A substituição fica por conta do `str_replace()` que procura por `(` e `)` e trocar por nada. Um novo array é gerado:

```
$array = array(
        "chave1" => "(valor1)",
        "chave2" => "(valor2)",
        "chave3" => "(valor3)"
);

$novo = array_map(function($item){return str_replace(array('(', ')'), array('', ''), $item);}, $array);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($n);
```

Outra opção é usar `array_walk()` ele faz quase a mesma coisa que `array_map()` porém não gera um novo array, como o argumento é passado por referência a alteração é feita no próprio elemento.

```
array_walk($array, function(&$item){ $item = str_replace(array('(', ')'), array('', ''), $item);});

echo "<pre>";
print_r($array);
```

Comment: Uma dúvida, em desempenho, o `array_map` supera uma estrutura de repetição? +1, ótima solução.

Comment: @lvcs não fiz nenhum teste de desempenho, o que posso dizer que `array_map()`/`array_walk()` podem ser mais práticos em algumas situações, evitando o `for`/`foreach`.

Comment: @Ivcs todas as funções nativas (escritas em C) são superiores em desempenho que qualquer estrutura criada com PHP puro.

Comment: @rray sim com certeza é mais prático :)

Comment: Funcionou direitinho!

Comment: uma dica seriá vc sempre optar por métodos próprios do PHP, como no caso de array_map(), pois ele estão otimizados para trabalhar da melhor forma com a linguagem.

Answer (score 5):

Você pode alterar facilmente utilizando a função `array_walk` em conjunto com uma boa expressão regular.

> array_walk - Apply a user supplied function to every member of an array

Como o manual diz, `array_walk` percorre todos os elementos de um array aplicando a cada um deles uma função fornecida como parâmetro.

Para remover os parênteses, utilizarei uma expressão regular. A `ER` em questão, é simples `\(([^()]+)\)`. Traduzindo, significa "tudo que estiver dentro de parênteses que não sejam parenteses".

Conforme já informado, é necessário fornecer uma função para `array_walk`. Nesse caso, será criada uma função como `callback`. A função é a seguinte:

```
$callback = function(&$value , $key) {
    preg_match('/\(([^()]+)\)/' , $value , $matches);

    $value = $matches[1];
};
```

Aplicando o seu array com o `callback`.

```
array_walk($array , $callback);
```

Obterá o seguinte resultado:

```
array(3) { ["chave1"]=> string(6) "valor1" ["chave2"]=> string(6) "valor2" ["chave3"]=> string(6) "valor3" }
```

Comment: Boa solução, ainda mais usando regex :)

Comment: @DiChrist, muito obrigado. Com a regex, você vai pegar somente o que existe entre parênteses. Caso houver valores externos, eles serão ignorados.

Answer (score 4):

Pode tentar assim:

```
foreach($array as $key => $value):
    $array[$key] = str_replace('(', '', $value);
    $array[$key] = str_replace(')', '', $array[$key]);
endforeach;
```

Basicamente percorri todos elementos do array e troquei `(` e `)` por nada.

Comment: Funcionou aqui mano!

Answer (score 4):

Você pode percorrer o array com um loop foreach, usar str_replace para tirar os parênteses e escrever os itens sem os parênteses em um novo array:

```
$parentheses = array('(', ')');
$newArray = [];
foreach ($array as $value) {
  $value = str_replace($parentheses, '', $value);
  $newArray[] = $value;
}
```

Comment: -1 pois não vai funcionar, `$value` é uma variável local da estrutura de repetição, quando você sai da estrutura de repetição e quando você percorre outro elemento do array ela deixa de existir, então é como que você não tivesse feito nada nessa estrutura de repetição, o correto seria usar `$array[$key]`, quando mudar eu retiro o -1.

Comment: Você está certo. Alterei a resposta para escrever um array novo, assim não fica duplicada, pois a sua resposta já faz o você comentou ;)

Comment: Outra forma de resolver o problema apontando é alterar o valor por referência, basta adicionar um `&` antes da variável ex:  `foreach ($array as &$value)`